# Excel concatenating a " quotation in string

Tags: excel, concatenation

I have the following sample data,

[image]

I want to concatenate string1 and string2 to produce the concatenation result

`"a" "b"`

using the `concatenate` function

I did not find any the answer in official microsoft excel documentation

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCATENATE-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d

How would I do this in excel? **Concatenate " quotation marks**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know it's not the prettiest solution but:

```
=CONCATENATE(CHAR(34) & A1 & CHAR(34), " " & CHAR(34) & B1 & CHAR(34))
```

or

```
=CONCATENATE(CHAR(34), A1, CHAR(34), " ", CHAR(34), B1, CHAR(34))
```

`CHAR(34)` can be used in place of ".

Edit:
If you prefer, CHAR(34) can be replaced with """", four double quote marks - for the same effect.

Comment: I had just looked this up and came to the same conclusion that `char(34)` has to be used. Found the resource here https://exceljet.net/formula/double-quotes-inside-a-formula.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. I'd be grateful for an accepted answer if that's alright :)